# Saving a file on desktop from a given url with a proxy server

Tags: python, proxy, urllib

My problem is that I want to save a file given by an url.
say the url is something like 'http://www.somesitename.com/Something/filename.fileextension"
for example 
some_url  = 'http://www.fordantitrust.com/files/python.pdf'
filename = myfile.pdf

I want to download this file.
I know I can do it easily with urllib.urlretrieve(some_url,filename) as soon as you dont't have any proxy in between your system and the requested url.

I am having a proxy so each time I want to download this file I have to pass that proxy.
I don't know how to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Urllib is deprecated since Python 2.6, use urllib2 instead. Genereally, proxy is handled by urllib2 transparently if a global proxy is set. If not, try use urllib2.proxyhandler to set your proxy.

Sample code from [python docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples) :

```
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://www.example.com:3128/'})
proxy_auth_handler = urllib2.ProxyBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('realm', 'host', 'username', 'password')

opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler)
# This time, rather than install the OpenerDirector, we use it directly:
opener.open('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```